# Nice Extension of Vector Field on Open Set to the Closure

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and suppose I have a vector field $F: U \to \mathbb{R}^n$.  Does there exist necessary and sufficient conditions on $U$ such that there is an 'as nice as $F$' vector field $\bar{F}: \bar{U} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\bar{U}$ is the closure of $U$?  In particular, is there a condition on $U$ that holds for all such vector fields within a certain class, say smooth.

Clearly if $U$ is a punctured open ball, for example, problems arise such as the usual counterexample of $d\theta$ on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$, which suggests some condition in the spirit of $U = \textrm{int}(\bar{U})$, but this seems likely insufficient generally.

Comment: if you have a halfspace, $(x,y), y>0$, say, -- which is as nice as it can get when it comes to boundary regulariy -- the counterexample $\theta$ still applies when you are asking about extension to the boundary. While you can integrage it in the half space, the origin will still cause a problem with regular exptension.

Comment: @Thomas I guess that suggests that it would be necessary for some extension to exist for something like the union of epsilon balls about each element of $U$.  Hmm.

Comment: You should start simple and look, e.g., for conditions to extend a continuous function on an open interval to the boundary of that interval. I'd expect this to be quite instructive already.

Comment: @Thomas In the spirit of the above discussion, I'd think passing to $\mathbb{R}$ loses a lot of the essential structure of the problem given there's only 'one way to approach' a given endpoint.

Comment: which makes the problem much simpler and will allow you to find most basics assumptions you need to impose for such a result to hold. You see, if you start out to understand Stokes theorem without knowing about the fundamental theorem of calculus you will, very likely, fail. But it's you searching for insight here.